# How to create JasperReport object from compiled .jasper file?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have compiled report (`.jasper` file). I need to get some info from that object (for example report name). How to do that ? If I could create [JasperReport](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperReport.html) object, i can call `getName()` method on it, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can get the JasperReport object by doing:

```
JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport)JRLoader.loadObject(new File("filename.jasper"));
```

from there you can get the name by doing:

```
jasperReport.getName()
```

Comment: I have a .jasper file, how do i create a PDF file?